# Double Inner Join generates unexpected error

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

In my database I have three tables:

- **Users:** UserID (Auto Numbering), UserName, UserPassword and a few other unimportant fields.
- **PrivateMessages:** MessageID (Auto Numbering), SenderID and a few other fields defining the message content.
- **MessageStatus:** MessageID, ReceiverID, MessageWasRead (Boolean)

What I need is a query to which I input a user's id and I get all the private messages he has received. In addition, I also need to receive each message's sender UserName. For this I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT Users.*, PrivateMessages.*, MessageStatus.*
FROM PrivateMessages
INNER JOIN Users ON PrivateMessages.SenderID = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN MessageStatus ON PrivateMessages.MessageID = MessageStatus.MessageID
WHERE MessageStatus.ReceiverID=[@userid];
```

But for some reason when I try saving it in my Access database, I get the following error (translated to English by me, since my office is in a different language):

> Syntax error (missing operator) at expression:
>   "PrivateMessages.SenderID = Users.UserID INNER JOIN MessageStatus ON
>   PrivateMessages.MessageID = MessageStatus.MessageI".

Any ideas what could cause this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses with MS Access:

```
SELECT Users.*, PrivateMessages.*, MessageStatus.*
FROM (PrivateMessages
INNER JOIN Users ON PrivateMessages.SenderID = Users.UserID)
INNER JOIN MessageStatus ON PrivateMessages.MessageID = MessageStatus.MessageID
WHERE MessageStatus.ReceiverID=[@userid];
```